# C# to Coldfusion for Base64String translation

Tags: c#, coldfusion, base64, azure-storage, coldfusion-9

Trying to convert C# code to CF and im stuck translating the following line

```
StorageKey = 'abcd';
Convert.FromBase64String(StorageKey)
```

The above line produces a byte array of 105,183,29

The line is taken from Azure's creating authorisation header;

```
System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 SHA256 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(StorageKey));
```

I've looked up FromBase64String Method on msdn library but its over my head. I hope someone can point me in the right Coldfusion direction.

I've tried BinaryDecode(StorageKey,"BASE64"), to me that seemed the most logical translation but im getting back 105-7329 which is not my expected result.

See Leigh's answer below for CF10+, if you are after a CF7-9 solution this my attempt

```
var javaMsg = javacast("string", arguments.sigMsg).getBytes("UTF-8");
var javaKey    = JavaCast("string", arguments.sigKey);
var myKey     = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec' );
var mac     = createObject('java', "javax.crypto.Mac");
var myKeyB64  = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64").decodeBase64(javaKey.getBytes());
var secret  = myKey.Init(myKeyB64, 'HmacSHA256');
mac         = mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
mac.init(secret);
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#mac.doFinal(javaMsg)#">
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you converting from C# to ColdFusion? What on earth is the business justification for this?

Comment: The documentation on creating signature is pitiful and the only example if found that which made sense to me is this C# version

Comment: @david-l - Can you post the example you are using? Because as I mentioned below, how the bytes are represented internally should not make any difference with an hmac signature.

Comment: added in description, didnt want to 'overwrite' your solution as being the answer.

Comment: Well if you came up with a better solution on your own - feel free to post it and mark it as the answer. You can always up-vote other answers that were helpful. (BTW, in the interest of completeness I added an example that should be compatible with CF7-9 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The line is taken from Azure's creating authorisation header;

mbeckish is correct about the sign differences between C# and CF/java. However, I do not think the internal representation should make any difference to your *end result*, which is usually all you care about. Normally you do not need to match the low level integer values, just the *string representation* of the bytes in base64 or hex. As long as you compare the final HMAC values in a common format, like base64, they should be exactly the same.

For example, if you take the [sample signature string here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sergeim/archive/2008/12/10/request-authorization-in-azure-sdk.aspx), both CF10 and C# return the same value. So it seems likely your problem is something else.

```
<cfscript>
    savecontent variable="signatureString" {
        WriteOutput("GET#chr(10)##chr(10)##chr(10)##chr(10)#x-ms-date:Mon, 01 Dec 2008 05:17:57 GMT#chr(10)#/accountname/queuename/messages");
    };
    key = binaryDecode("abcd", "base64");
    resultInHex = hmac(signatureString, key,"HMACSHA256");
    // result: wxR7Bt6sWEKVJ9vEjCiuqA8OKCZOKYfbxaXj85whOkM=
    WriteDump(binaryEncode(binaryDecode(resultInHex, "hex"), "base64"));
</cfscript>
```

**EDIT:** I know there are a bunch of pre-CF10 hmac functions floating around. But many of them forget about encoding. Here is a generic adaptation that accepts an algorithm ("hmacsha256", "hmacsha1", ..) and encoding ("utf-8"). It *should* work with CF7-9.

```
<cfset result = hmacX( signatureString, "abcd", "HmacSHA256") />
<cfdump var="#result#" />

<cffunction name="hmacX" returntype="string" hint="">
    <cfargument name="message" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="keyInBase64" type="any" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="algorithm" type="string" default="HmacSHA256" />
    <cfargument name="encoding" type="string" default="UTF-8" />

    <cfset var dataBytes  = charsetDecode( arguments.message, arguments.encoding ) />
    <cfset var keyBytes  = binaryDecode( arguments.keyInBase64, "base64" ) />
    <cfset var keySpec = createObject("java", "javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec") />
    <cfset var secret = keySpec.init( keyBytes, arguments.algorithm ) />
    <cfset var mac  = createObject("java", "javax.crypto.Mac").getInstance( arguments.algorithm ) />

    <cfset mac.init( secret ) />

    <cfreturn binaryEncode( mac.doFinal(dataBytes), "base64") />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Thank you leigh, this is exact solution although I came up with an answer of my own this afternoon. Im using CF8 so hmac() will not work but im sure it will help others. I've gone down the Java route. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, there are a few [cf/java versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951477/calculate-hmac-sha256-digest-in-coldfusion-using-java) floating around. Just be sure to supply the same encoding used by C# when grabbing the data bytes ie `String.getBytes("UTF-8")` or better yet .. use [`charsetDecode(yourString, "UTF-8")`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f64.html)

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, obviously the signatures need to be exact, cant have anything that could upset them.

Comment: Yep, hashing is *very* sensitive. One wrong character makes it cry .. or it does things that make you want to cry ;-)

Answer (score 1):

C# is treating the results as unsigned bytes, while ColdFusion is treating them as signed bytes.

The values under 128 are the same in both C# and ColdFusion, while the values that are over 128 in C# are negative (the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)) in ColdFusion.

So, to convert back, add 256 to any negative values.

**EDIT**

This might not be a problem with the actual bytes returned from BinaryDecode.  It could just be a problem with how ColdFusion decides to print out those bytes to the screen during your debugging.

Compare the actual binary values you get from C# and ColdFusion (for example, by saving the values to a binary file rather than printing to the screen).