# ColdFusion hash_hmac256 output format / encoding

Tags: coldfusion, character-encoding

I have this script to output an hash_hmac similar function in CFML:

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding = "iso-8859-1">

<cfset msg = "AgostinoSqueglinPiccolinMonachin">

<cfset jMsg = JavaCast("string",msg).getBytes() />
<cfset jKey = JavaCast("string","cicciolin").getBytes() />


<cfset key = createObject("java","javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec") />
<cfset mac = createObject("java","javax.crypto.Mac") />

<!--- this line had to be changed to the 256 version --->
<cfset key = key.init(jKey,"hmacSHA256") />

<cfset mac = mac.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm()) />
<cfset mac.init(key) />
<cfset mac.update(jMsg) />

<cfset cc = mac.doFinal()>

<cfset strBase64Value = ToString( cc,"Utf-8" ) />

<cfscript>
    writeDump(msg);
    writeDump(strBase64Value);
</cfscript>
```

This should output the same result as this php:

```
<?php

    $uu = hash_hmac('sha256', "AgostinoSqueglinPiccolinMonachin", "cicciolin", true);

    echo $uu;

?>
```

But I got this different result, due probably to an format error:

ColdFusion : �GK�襍}Ÿ�}��B�}9w�(���u�m�

PHP: ÐGKÒè¥}Å¸»}©ì¬B§}9w´(«æüu§mÃ

Seems some characters does not output in the correct way.

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE:**

The solution works perfectly, but there are other problem if I try to encode new line:

for example

Php:

```
$sign = "GET\n" . "agostinsqueglin" . "". "piccolin";

$uu = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $sign, "cicciolin", true));
```

If I try with:

```
sign = "GET#chr(13)##chr(10)#" & "agostinsqueglin" & "" & "piccolin";
```

I got two different results.

This is due to the way coldfusion handling "\n" newline...

Comment: Don't edit new questions into existing questions - start a new question (link to the old one if relevant).

Comment: However... PHP `"GET\n"` => CFML `"GET#chr(10)#"` only (or `"GET"&chr(10)` )

Comment: (`chr(13)` is `\r` and rarely needed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you've provided is a little more long-winded than it needs to be, and ... well, here's an improved version:

```
<cfscript>
    msg       = "AgostinoSqueglinPiccolinMonachin";
    key       = "cicciolin";
    algorithm = "HmacSHA256";
    encoding  = "iso-8859-1";

    secret = createObject('java',"javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec").init( charsetDecode(key,encoding) , algorithm );
    mac    = createObject('java',"javax.crypto.Mac").getInstance(algorithm);
    mac.init(secret);
    digest = mac.doFinal( charsetDecode(msg,encoding) );

    writeDump( msg );
    writeDump( toString(digest,encoding) );
</cfscript>
```

This is based on the answer and comments here: [Calculate HMAC-SHA256 digest in ColdFusion using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951477/calculate-hmac-sha256-digest-in-coldfusion-using-java/951782#951782)

Obviously for regular use it should be wrapped up in a suitable function.

Comment: Yeah! I've solved this problem adding the ascii encode:

`jMsg = JavaCast("string",msg).getBytes("iso-8859-1")`

but your solution is very elegant...

Comment: @user1468116 - You should also specify the encoding with `jKey` as well. (Though you do not really need `getBytes()`, the built in `charsetDecode` function does the same thing). Either way,  *always* specify the encoding whenever converting a string => bytes or vice-versa for consistent results (like in Peter's example).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to output a UTF-8 string while your processingdirective is set to iso-8859-1.  Try changing it:

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding = "UTF-8">
```

Comment: To match the PHP value, the correct change seems to be the other way round - **switching the ToString call to `iso-8859-1`**.